# hyperpolic function integration in maple

Tags: maple

Im trying to evaluate this function in maple

[image]

but I keep getting this answer, why isn't maple integrating properly. I tried numerically integrating it and it works but I need the analytical solution too.

Answer (score 0):

```
restart;

sig := x->(exp((x-t)/a)-exp((-x-t)/a))
          /(exp((x-t)/a)+exp((-x-t)/a)):

new := convert(simplify(convert(expand(sig(x)),trigh)),tanh);

                     new := tanh(x/a)

simplify(expand(convert(sig(x) - new, exp)));

                           0
```

Now, you originally wrote `int(f*sig(x)/x,x)`.

You didn't indicate that `f` was a function of `x`, and as a mere constant it's not really important and could simply be pulled out in front of the integral as a constant factor. If `f` is some function of `x` then you really need to state what it is!

Let's consider `int(sig(x)/x,x=c..d)`. Using the simplification `new`, that is just,

```
Q := Int( new/x, x=c..d );

      Q := Int(tanh(x/a)/x, x = c .. d)

QQ := IntegrationTools:-Change(Q, y=x/a, y);

     QQ := Int(tanh(y)/y, y = c/a .. d/a)
```

You said that you wanted an "analytical solution" by which I take it you mean an explicit formula for the symbolic integration result. But what do you want if the integral does not (mathematically) have a closed form exact, symbolic result?

Would you be content with an (exact, symbolic) series approximation?

```
H := (a,ord,c,d)
     -> int(convert(series(eval(new/x,:-a=a),x,ord),
                    polynom),x=c..d):

# order 5
H(a, 5, c, d);

                      3    3     /  5    5\
            d - c   -c  + d    2 \-c  + d /
            ----- - -------- + ------------
              a          3            5    
                      9 a         75 a
```

For a specific example, taking `a=2` and an (exact) series approximation of order 25, then the integral from `x=0` to `x=1` gets evaluated as an exact rational.

```
evalf(H(2, 25, 0, 1));

                      0.4868885956
```

Here's the numeric integration for those same values,

```
evalf(Int( eval(new/x,a=2), x=0..1 ));

                      0.4868885956
```

Specialized numeric quadrature could be as good as a series approximation for a variety of applications, but of course that would depend on what you intend on doing with the result.

This raises the question: what do you hope to do with some supposed "analytical result" that you cannot do with a black-box function that generates the floating-point numeric approximation? Why do you "need" an "analytic result"?

BTW, another way to simplify it (in case the construction above of `new` does not succeed in your Maple version):

```
new := convert(simplify(expand( numer(sig(x))/exp(-t/a) ))
               /simplify(expand( denom(sig(x))/exp(-t/a) )),
               compose,trigh,tanh);

                                /x\
                     new := tanh|-|
                                \a/
```